# Teradata LIKE ANY causing duplicates

Tags: teradata, sql-like

I have a query which looks something like below which aim is to see if a two letter code exists in a string. If it does, set a column to yes, if it doesnt set a column to no

```
SELECT ID,
    case when Table_a.item LIKE ANY ('%AA%','%AB%','%AC%','%AD%','%AE%','%FF%',' %GG%','%HR%','%TR%','%ST%','%VL%') THEN 'YES' else 'NO' end AS foo,
item 
FROM Table_a
```

Unfortunately its causing rows to appear twice

```
ID      foo    item     
112     yes    AA-FF-TT-RR
112     no     AA-FF-TT-RR
```

Does anyone know why. 
Am i misusing the `LIKE ANY` function
We are not on Teradata 14 yet

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you post your actual SQL? The current pseudo-code doesn't make sense.

Comment: hi @dnoeth, i have updated the SQL, In reality everything isn't in a single table but it should make more sense now

Comment: The 2nd row can't be caused by the LIKE, it's probably due to the join(s).

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, Thanks again for replying, Shouldn't a Distinct fix this? (it doesn't)

Comment: DISTINCT should not be used to fix a bad query :-)

Comment: Agreed :)...let me look at it again